# Can I say: "What movie/novel is this?"

Tags: word-usage, questions

This might be the easiest question, but it is confusing me a lot. A friend of mine shared a photo of a movie. So, if I asked "What movie is this?", would it be correct?

Secondly, if a friend uploads a picture of a page from a novel page she is reading, and I ask "What novel is this?" Would it be correct too?

Comment: Related: [What (color hair vs. hair color) do you have?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13465/3281)

Answer (score 1):

This is common usage, but "Which movie is this from?", or "Which novel is this from," is better.

Comment: But I've been always taught that if only one thing is given, you're supposed to say "what".

Comment: There are thousands of movies; which is this from?  But honestly, it is more common to hear native speakers ask these questions the way they are worded in your question.